# How to use doxygen in a project containing both C++ and Python (multi-programming language project)

Tags: python, c++, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am creating documentation for my project which has codes written in both C++ and Python. I can generate documentation with doxygen on my C++ codes, but find no way to do the same with my Python codes after I have the former files. And if I need both doxygen documents to appear under the same index.html, i.e. to merge them into one uniform doxygen file, how can I do this? What is the convention that everyone uses?

Comment: Please see the documentation chapter "Documenting the code" paragraph "Comment blocks in Python". It is just possible to use C++ and Python code in one run, it goes automatically.

Comment: According to the Doxygen documentation, it should automatically pick up `*.py` and `*.pyw` files. Just put the Doxygen commands in the Python code as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, thank you [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert) and [shawnhcorey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604642/shawnhcorey) for your  quick responses. 
I tried what you suggested, and made the following modifications to parse documentation comments from files written in both languages:

**In Doxyfile**

INPUT = include/my_package/ scripts/my_package/

Both directories are separated by space.

Then,

FILE_PATTERNS = *.h *.py

The two wildcards patterns are also separated by a space.

Back to where you placed your doxyfile, then run

```
doxygen
```

And off you go!